# Transacciones en MYSQL no funcionan?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy realizando transacciones pero no funcionan, he visto ejemplos y esta igual, aqui les muestro mi transaccion:

```
    public static function finishpackage($room, $finish_date) {
    $connection = self::connect();
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    
    try {

        $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet, start_date) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets, 
        start_date FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
        
        $query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `finished_products` SET `finish_date`=:finish_date WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["finish_date"=>$finish_date, "room"=>$room]);
        
        $query = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $result = $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
       
        $connection->commit();
        
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        $connection->rollBack();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Se supone que si una de esas consultas falla o tiene algún error de sintaxis debería cancelarse totalmente, pero no, este la ignora y sigue ejecutando.

Por ejemplo, si yo cambiase el nombre de la tabla de la segunda consulta a `finished_productssss`, este hace la primera y la tercera consulta, la segunda la deja, imprimo por la consola de `js` el error y este me dice que hay error en la linea en donde el nombre de la tabla esta mal, las transacciones solo se cancelan por error del servidor, sintaxis? porque de verdad no entiendo porque se ejecuta si la segunda consulta como dije tiene el nombre de la tabla mal

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motor de las tablas de la base de datos, MyISAM o InnoDB?

Comment: Dónde puedo ver eso? Simplemente estoy usando xampp y ya JAJAJAJAJAJAJAJAJJAJ A, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Si tienes XAMPP ve al phpMyAdmin, pincha en el nombre de la base de datos para que te muestre todas las tablas, y verás un columna Type o Tipo donde dice si son MyISAM, InnoDB, etc.

Comment: Pregunta: `$connection` es instancia de PDO?